# Oracle database number type field not storing the value I put in

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

In oracle, when I try to save this value into a number type field: 37788024213340160 it gets converted to this: 3.77880242133402E16

Which is bad because it is rounding the value up, and I need it to keep the exact value that I put into the field.

Any idea how to stop this from happening?

In case this helps, here is the exact definition of the field in question (MIN_ID):

```
    create table SUBGRP
    (
      ID                         NUMBER not null, 
      NAME                       VARCHAR2(128) not null, 
      MIN_ID                     NUMBER
    )
```

Comment: please show the exact definition of the field . preferably the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: I'd wager that the problem is that whatever front-end you have (`SQL*Plus`?) is displaying the data using scientific notation and is doing the rounding.  What front-end are you using?  If you are using SQL*Plus, set the format to display however many digits you want to see.

Answer (score 4):

It's just a formatting / display issue:

```
  SQL> create table subgrp (
    2    id  number not null,
    3    name   varchar2(128)  not null,
    4    min_id    number
    5  );

  Table created.

  SQL> insert into subgrp values ( 123, 'test', 37788024213340160 );

  1 row created.

  SQL> commit;

  Commit complete.

  SQL> select * from subgrp;

          ID
  ----------
  NAME
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      MIN_ID
  ----------
         123
  test
  3.7788E+16


  SQL> col min_id format 999999999999999999999999999
  SQL> /

          ID
  ----------
  NAME
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        MIN_ID
  ----------------------------
         123
  test
             37788024213340160


  SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue of PL/SQL Developer rounding up and displaying the value as 15 digits in scientific notation rather than displaying the original entire number, was causing my Web Application to also display the incorrect rounded-up number.

After some research, I decided to try changing a setting in the preferences of PL/SQL Developer so that the entire number would get shown. This did the trick and now when I query for the value it displays correctly in PL/SQL and in my Web Application!

To do this, I did the following:

```
Tools -> Preferences -> SQL Window -> (Select this): Number fields to_char
```

Also, you can wrap the reads to the column with to_char() and this will display the correct unformatted value.

Comment: PL/SQL is a language.  It sounds like you are saying that a setting in your GUI was the issue.  Perhaps your GUI is PL/SQL Developer from AllAround Automations?

Comment: Yes, I meant to put PL/SQL Developer. Thanks!

Comment: Here is a forum where they talk about this issue, for reference: http://forums.allroundautomations.com/ubb/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=37245